# Calendaring customization [highlighting the current month]

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, calendar

I made a method that writes a view with a calendar table which shows all months of a year using the calendaring class.

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

    public function this_year() {
        $data['title'] = 'Calendar: ' . date('Y');
        $this->load->library('calendar');
        $prefs = array(
            'local_time' => 'none',
            'start_day' => 'sunday',
            'month_type' => 'long',
            'day_type' => 'short',
            'show_next_prev' => FALSE,
            'show_other_days' => TRUE,
            'template' => '
        {table_open}<table class="table table-condensed">{/table_open}
        {heading_row_start}<tr class="info">{/heading_row_start}
        {cal_cell_start_today}<td class="today">{/cal_cell_start_today}
        {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-day">{/cal_cell_start_other}
    '
        );
        $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
        $data['calendar'] = '<table class="table-calendar"><tr>';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                $data['calendar'].= "<td>{$this->calendar->generate(date('Y'), $i)}</td>";
                $data['calendar'].= '</tr><tr>';
            }
            else {
                $data['calendar'].= "<td>{$this->calendar->generate(date('Y'), $i)}</td>";
            }
        }
        $data['calendar'].= '</tr></table>';
        $this->template->load('template/index', __CLASS__ . "/" . __FUNCTION__, $data);
    }

}
```

*On VIEW, just echo '$calendar'

It works as well, and returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mKJH.png).

But I didn't found a way to highlight only the current month using a template in the calendaring class. I tried to modify the default template but it doesn't work because when I change the class of `{heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}`, it modifies all the month's labels like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wAGH.png).

I'm using the default methods (same code) from the basic class tutorial. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add some code... You probably need to do some PHP to add a conditional class: e.g. for january: `<?php if(date('n') == 1){ $cssClass = 'active'; } ?>`
and then apply styling to `.heading_row_start.active`

Comment: Hey @reinder, thanks for the attention. I added my controller source code. I'm thinking that to do something like this I'll need to modify the core of CodeIgniter. I prefer to do using the native methods or extending the native classes/methods with my own code in the application context. Any opinions to help out? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to [extend](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=extending#extending-native-libraries) `CI_Calendar` to force the method `generate()` pass his `$month` variable to the `parse_template()` method. Then, `parse_template($month)` will be able to apply an exception while parsing the declared template on `{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}`:

`CI_Calendar::parse_template($month), 483`:

```
if($val == 'heading_row_start'){
  if( $month == date('m')){
    $this->replacements[$val] = '<tr class="info">';
  }
}
else{
  $this->replacements[$val] = $match[1];
}
```